# calling a method from same class in xcode

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode6

i want to call a method "shows()" but why i am getting the error that "expected identifier or ( " and "use of undeclared identifier self"

ViewController.m

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
{
    NSDictionary *inventory;
}
- (void)shows;
@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
inventory = @{@"Rahul":[NSNumber numberWithInt:11],
              @"iOS":[NSNumber numberWithInt:22]};
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning {
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

  - (void)shows
    {
      NSLog(@"%@",inventory);
    }


     [self shows];
@end
```

Comment: here is the screenshot of error http://screencast.com/t/DR604TYpBF

Comment: call **[self shows];** inside any one of method

Comment: i didn't understand. I have to make another method ?

Comment: Your calling Method outside of function , call in viewdidload or any other method with in the brasses

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't call `[view shows];` in the class scope, you need to call it within a method, like in `viewDidLoad`
Call it like this:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
      [super viewDidLoad];
      inventory = @{@"Rahul":[NSNumber numberWithInt:11],
          @"iOS":[NSNumber numberWithInt:22]};
      // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
      [self shows];//SHOWS call moved here...

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can't call this method outside. You can call it inside of anyother method. Like you can call this method in `ViewDidLoad`.

```
 - (void)viewDidLoad { 
       [super viewDidLoad];    
       [self shows];   
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to place the code in another method, it can't be left in the open by it self.

Put it in your `viewDidLoad:` method or elsewhere